# Cocoa NSTextField value not changed

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextfield

I created `NSTextfield` programmatically:

```
func createText(point:NSPoint) {
        let txtFld = AnnotationTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(point.x, point.y, 360,40))
        txtFld.isEnabled = true
        txtFld.delegate = self
        self.contentView.addSubview(txtFld)
        txtFields.append(txtFld)

        txtFld.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

But when I click on another field or hit `Enter` key, my string not saving.

[image]

Comment: From the docmentation of `becomeFirstResponder`: "Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder(_:) method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly.".

Comment: Which methods did you override in `AnnotationTextField`? Where does "Enter your text here" come from? What happens when you use a `NSTextfield`?

Answer (score 0):

I set `stringValue` in draw method. That was my fault